# Кэширование HTML и как его отключить

Tags: php, nginx

Привет. У меня есть веб-приложение, состоящее из html-разметки и встроенного `<?php ?>` кода. Я реализовал вставку скриптов и стилей при помощи создания файла **config.php**, в котором создал переменные `$stylesheets` и `$scripts`. И создал переменную `$env`, где я указываю текущее состояние окружения разработки. Если я указываю `$env = 'dev'`, то загружаются различные не минифицированные файлы из папки **/dev/**, а если устанавливаю `$env = 'production'`, то используются файлы из папки **/assets/**, прошедшие сборку, минификацию и прочее через Gulp. Но вот у меня какая-то беда с этим всем. Я перенёс файлы изображений и папки **/img** в **assets/img/**, и пошёл менять пути в html. Заменяю атрибут `src="/img/flags/ru.png"` на `src="/assets/img/flags/ru.png"`, а изменение происходит в html не сразу. И перезагрузка без кэша не помогает. То же самое происходит и с php. Если я устанавливаю `$env = 'dev'`, то какое-то время на странице всё ещё отображаются файлы, загружаемые из продакшн-папки. Раньше такого никогда не было. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может кэшироваться html и как это отключить? Установлен Nginx 1.12.0 и PHP7.0 с FPM. Memcached не установлен.

Comment: Сайт удаленно правите? Он сейчас работает - в "мир" смотрит или локально запущен? Можете ссылку на него дать?

Comment: Можете настройки NGINX вашего виртуального холста выложить? И вот тут также можете почитать https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-caching

Comment: Или вот например, ответ в вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098108/how-to-use-http-caching-in-nginx-for-html-files

Comment: Или лучше вот - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-centos-7

Answer (score 2):

**Через переменную для нескольких типов файлов, например**

```sh
# ...

# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    expires $expires;

# ...
```

> Для `text/html` мы устанавливаем значение в `epoch`. Это особое
>   значение, которое явно выражается в отсутствии кеширования, что
>   заставляет браузер всегда спрашивать, обновлен ли сам веб-сайт (ресурс).

**Или только для html/htm файлов**

```sh
server {

    # ....

    location ~* \.(?:html?)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    # ....

}
```

Не забудьте перезагрузить NGINX после изменений.

---

- [Модуль ngx_http_headers_module](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html)
- В руководстве [How to Implement Browser Caching with Nginx's header Module on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-centos-7) (англ.) также найдете информацию как тестируется кэширование того или иного ресурса (JS, CSS, картинки, HTML и т.д.).
- [Настройка Nginx Expires](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+Nginx+Expires)

Comment: Блин, через мобилу не могу оформить должным образом ( Посмотрите по ссылкам что скинул.

Comment: А разве text/html кэшируется, если для него не указан `expires`?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin _По умолчанию все файлы будут иметь одинаковое поведение кэширования по умолчанию._ Нужно изучать, что в вашем случае. Выполните команду, например, `curl -I http://localhost/test.html` — и смотрите заголовки.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin добавил в ответ ещё кое что. Но предже чем менять, я бы посмотрел заголовки ответа ресурсов (html). Они у вас PHP обрабатываются, не должно кешироваться. Смотрите настройки. Или в самим скриптах не кешируете ничего?